# Here There Be Dragons

Tags: meaning-in-context, subjunctive-mood

The following is an [excerpt](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/08/12/world/asia/indonesia-komodo-national-park-dragons.html) from the August 12 *New York Times*.
What does the headline “Here There Be Dragons” mean?

> **Here There Be Dragons. But Can They Survive an Invasion of Tourists?**
>
> KOMODO NATIONAL PARK, Indonesia — The Komodo dragon, a 10-foot lizard native only to a scattering of islands in Indonesia, flicked its forked tongue. Two boys were standing nearby, the perfect size for dragon snacks.
>
> A local guide shrugged at their unease and urged them closer to the reptile.　Komodo dragons resemble dinosaurs that missed their cue for extinction. […]
> But like other tourist destinations around the world, from Venice to the Galápagos, the park is at risk of being wrecked by its own popularity. The inundation of tourists is threatening the very animals and pristine beauty drawing them there.

Comment: Nice question...it is a reference to old world maps, and falling off an edge as  a point of no return. This might also qualify as an etymology question tag.

Comment: 'be' is faux-pirate speak. No one ever mentions the oxymoronic 'here there'.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons

Comment: Of course, when speaking of the Komodo park, it's a reference to "Komodo dragons", a sort of reptile.

Comment: The title is a sort of parody of the original translated Latin phrase "**Here be dragons**" (hic sunt dracones)

Comment: @Mitch why is it oxymoronic? The non-standard grammar is the use of 'be' instead of 'are' and if the quote said "Here there are dragons" no one would think twice about it.

Comment: @BoldBen 'here there' seems oxymoronic if considered alone.

Comment: @Mitch but it's not "here there" in isolation; it's "here" and the compound verb "there are" in combination with it. The verb usage is the same as saying "There are dragons over there" or  "In the mountais there are dragons", it's just that they are using the pronoun "here" instead of "In the mountains".

Answer (score 3):

In the early days of cartography, when many regions were unknown and uncharted, the cartographer would frequently draw a dragon or a sea monster where no information was available about the geography of that region. This was at a time when there was still some degree of mythology, and many genuinely believed that there were dragons and sea monsters in the world.

The phrase and the drawings did serve an important purpose, however. When one is in uncharted waters, a higher level of caution is warranted, because there are likely to be hazards that are not yet known which could indeed jeopardize the safety of a ship and its crew.

The term is somewhat analogous to the story in the Odyssey of the Scylla and Charybdis, the "rock and a hard place", which Odysseus' ship was compelled to sail between, where there were two very real but poorly understood hazards. They were both described as monsters on opposite sides of a narrow strait, when in reality, one was a whirlpool and the other was a treacherously rocky coast. Those two hazards were compounded by the fast currents within the strait that could push a ship toward either of the hazards. Many ships were destroyed by these hazards, and the tall tales of the day led sailors to imagine, and then spread rumors, of monsters that were wreaking havoc intentionally.

Thus the phrase "here there be dragons" gradually came into being, as a metaphor representing man's fear of the unknown, which was partly based in reason, and partly based in irrational exaggeration of a threat that was poorly understood and was therefore thought to be worse than it actually was, to the extent of becoming supernaturally menacing in the imaginations of explorers.

In the context of this particular headline, it is a double entendre, on the one hand referring to the Komodo dragons themselves, and on the other hand referring to the fact that when a region became commonly traversed, and the hazards that were present became well understood and easily avoided, the illusion of dragons vanished, just as certain rare species, like Komodo dragons, sometimes also vanish due to increasing human traffic and population, but in this case, the dragons vanish due to loss of habitat rather than loss of imaginary supernatural dangers through better understanding of the real hazard.

Comment: The actual original phrase is translated from Latin *hic sunt dracones*, which was translated as **Here be dragons** Note that *there* was not used, as it is essentially superfluous.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I could make a case that the 'there' is not totally superfluous. The sentence can be considered a transformation of 'There are dragons here', and 'there are' has the [expletive or dummy 'there'.](https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/there-is.html)

Comment: @mitch Shouldn't it then be "*There are/be here Dragons*"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I would have thought moving the adverb to the front would be the way it's done, eg with time "Yesterday there were dragons."

Comment: I upvoted this—but it would be great if you could include some kind of [objective reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons) (with attribution and quotation) that helps verify the claim you're making. I agree with it, but a good answer really needs something that makes it more than just personal opinion.

Comment: It's not personal opinion. It's a statement of fact. Anyone can verify the statements themselves. They can read the Odyssey. They can google the phrase. I'm sorry, but that's not how I write. I speak the truth from my own knowledge. That's my personal prerogative. Not providing citations does not make my arguments or my statements of fact any less valid. The answer was correct, and considerably better written qualitatively than most volunteers would be able to write it. I stand by my work.

Comment: Supporting evidence makes an answer watertight. It's difficult that someone can dispute your credentials, your experience, or your expertise if you can support your ideas (or facts). This is common and standard policy in all sorts of academic fields, unless you have established yourself as an authority. And, by the way, I was the first to upvote the answer. So...

Comment: I appreciate your support. Thank you. I am doing my best to contribute high quality work to this site. I'm not a researcher, though. I'm more of a poet and a proponent of military and political policy, who also happens to have a very thorough knowledge of history, which together with my background in literature informs my knowledge of English. I completed my Master's, and I will probably never again write a citation, thankfully. If someone doubts something I say, I'll argue it with them. But in this case, no one doubted it, because it was watertight. Claims to the contrary are unprovable. :)

Comment: I don't mean to toot my own horn, but I am generally recognized as an authority, eventually, by my own virtues, intellect and merits, wherever I engage in a debate or present my work. Quality speaks for itself. I love to write, but I hate to cite. If my work is appreciated, my prose sophisticated... why must the truth be reiterated? Shall the muses be asphyxiated?

Comment: -1 @GabrielM Have you understood the question?